# Image Conversion: (150,150) -> (150,150,3)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

img = test_features[0, :, :, 0:1]
print(img.shape)
# (150,150,1)
```

I don't know how to convert this image to (150,150,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tile`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: img = np.ones((150, 150, 1))

In [3]: new = np.tile(img, 3)

In [4]: new.shape
Out[4]: (150, 150, 3)
```

For example, if `img` was:

```
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3]],

       [[4],
        [5],
        [6]],

       [[7],
        [8],
        [9]]])
```

`np.tile(img, 3)` would be:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]],

       [[7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [9, 9, 9]]])
```